# Среднее кол-во запросов к базе у сайтов

Tags: php, база-данных

Сколько в среднем, Ваш сайт делает запросов к базе данных, при загрузке одной страницы?

На wp зашел к ним на сайт, у них на главной - 3 запроса, а в просмотре категорий - 5 запросов. Работает мгновенно...

Разрабатываю сейчас свой сайт, и смотрю что получается до 10ти запросов при каждом запросе на страницу, думаю, не многовато ли

Есть запрос у меня, который выводит весь основной контент, индексы - проставлены, но в нем есть несколько JOIN-ов и подзапросов, читаю - что такие запросы очень тяжело идут...

Вот пример запроса

```
SELECT  s.*,
        vip.name AS `vip_name`, vip.css_class AS `vip_css_class`
        FROM `servers` s
        LEFT JOIN `projects` p ON p.id = s.project_id
        LEFT JOIN `vips` vip ON vip.id = s.vip_id
        WHERE 
            p.game_id = 1 AND s.status = 1
        ORDER BY 
            s.position ASC
        LIMIT 
            0, 100;
```

Вот что выдаёт explain
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем сразу валить все запросы? - Ну даже раз на то пошло, используйте кеширование и будет вам счастье.

Comment: @And что значит сразу все запросы? Эти запросы у меня отдают контент необходимый, лишних нет

Comment: wp работает мгновенно? Ставил я его как-то для теста на локальный компьютер. Время генерации страниц было больше 2 секунд :)

Comment: @Visman я открыл их офф сайт, и хоть я сижу с моб. интернета - то у меня там главная страница прогрузилась мгновенно, и в исходном коде написано - 3 querys.

Comment: Зачем на главной 10 запросов? Бредятина полнейшая. Только если вы не понимаете, как оптимизировать и использовать кеш- это уже другой вопрос. да и вобоще, wp, jm, etc... - все что дальше базируется на основе этих источников - мусор.

Comment: @And у меня не базируется, у меня просто есть класс для работы с базой, и его использую. Кэш нельзя делать - так как у меня должны отображаться результаты максимально быстро, без кэша.

Comment: Ну во первых, в вашем случае, уж точно использование `count(*)` и всякие `s.*` - буду работать медленно. Дальше, почитайте про `QC` - `Query Chache`

Comment: Кстати, join, о котором вы беспокоитесь раз в 10 быстрее подзапроса в списке выборки (который практически как отдельно выполняемый запрос для каждой строки выборки) да еще с count(). Как вам правильно сказали, такие данные лучше где то кешировать. Или на худой конец преобразовать в join, при этом проведя оптимизацию для limit выполнив его заранее, до join'ов, в виде `select ... from (select * from servers where status = 1 order by position ASC limit 0,50) s LEFT JOIN ...` Но в любом случае надо смотреть план выполнения запроса (по explain) и подбирать наиболее быстрый вариант

Comment: И не берите за аксиому никаких утверждений на счет join и того, что я сказал выше. в каждом конкретном случае оптимизатор может повести себя не так как ожидалось, все зависит от данных и например подзапрос в списке выборки окажется быстрее, а один конкретный join будет дико тормозить в то время как остальные будут летать. И кстати с вынесением limit я показал только общий подход, вам туда похоже надо будет перенести и projects. Я его не заметил, потому у вас стоит LEFT (который это условие собой полностью уничтожает) и оптимизатор то же может не заметить и дать худший план

Comment: @Mike от подзапроса отказался, остались только join-ы, но не вижу возможности убрать их, только изменить на INNER-ы, первые два, а LEFT с vips - так и останется, ибо не всегда может быть вип привязан.

Comment: Ну в LEFT ничего плохого нет, единственное его влияние на оптимизатор - он понимает что с этой таблицы выполнение начинать не надо, потому что она не обязательна. И часто именно это и требуется для правильной оптимизации. А вот понимание, что projects обязательна для оптимизатора очень важно, в случае, если серверов очень много (а по status их отбирать бесполезно из за низкой селективности) то наиболее верным путем для оптимизатора будет начать с projects. С inner больше вероятность, что он именно так и поступит.

Comment: Кстати, зачем в запросе участвует таблица games, данные из нее не выбираются и на количество строк результата она не влияет ... А если из нее все таки что то получается, то попробуйте написать g.id=? вместо p.game_id=? и посмотрите по плану выполнения как поведет себя оптимизатор. может оказаться, что так лучше (или хуже, но менее вероятно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотря какой сайт. Бывает и по 20-30 обращений к БД на один запрос для сложных проектов (и это при хорошей оптимизации, когда информация в списках и прочих цикличных вещах вытаскивается одним запросом, а не несколькими десятками).

Другое вопрос в размере самой базы. Использовать запросы с JOIN'ами на больших таблицах не самый быстрый вариант. Лучше выполнять денормализацию данных или использовать сводные таблицы в таких случаях.

Запрос, который вы привели не оптимизирован. Советую сделать следующее:

1. Не запрашивать данные сразу из 4 таблиц, а объединить все в одну
2. Запросы с `count(*)` на InnoDB не самые быстрые. Лучше хранить данные счетчика в промежуточной таблице, а при операциях, связанные с его увеличением/уменьшением  вносить соответствующие изменения в эту таблицу.
3. Эта запись `WHERE s.status = 1 AND p.game_id = $game_id` во-первых, потенциально небезопасная. Оберните $game_id в кавычки. Во-вторых, для увеличения производительности лучше поменять местами условия поиска `WHERE p.game_id = '$game_id' AND s.status = 1` (так мы сразу ищем строку по уникальному game_id, а не перебираем все варианты со status = 1, коих будет большинство).
4. По поводу индексов - имейте ввиду, что при каждом конкретном запросе используется только ОДИН индекс (составной или простой). Желательно не ставить индексы на все подряд колонки, которые используются в WHERE или ORDER. Все равно толку от этого не будет, а UPDATE или INSERT будут занимать больше времени. Смотрите профиль нагрузки и явно задавайте индекс (INDEX) при сложных запросах.
5. На часто запрашиваемых, но редко изменяемых данных помогает кэширование (Memcached).

Comment: `Оберните $game_id в кавычки.` не поможет.

Comment: @Visman почему же нет?

Comment: @Visman $game_id есть int, можно в кавычки int ведь не запихивать. Кэширование использую, но как быть при при поиске данных, если кэшировать? В кэш можно запихнуть сериализованный массив, но если пользователь будет по game_id тому-же искать, то перебирать массив из N значений циклом - будет затруднительгнее чем из базы

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov как объеденить данные из всех таблиц в одну, если это все независимые друг от друга таблицы? Не понял момента

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov, кавычки от sql-инъекции не спасут.

Comment: @user190134, если эта переменная у вам не может принимать ни какое значение кроме int, то можно оставить и так. Но лучше использовать подготовленные выражения http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Не поможет, по одной простой причине - вы не используете экранирование, на ваши кавычки до балды. Ну да, ну да! Дак и экранинг может не помочь, по одной простой причине - не верно указанна кодировка соединения с базой данных. Ну, а дальше, больше =)

Comment: @user190134 Кстати, у многих СУБД есть кеширование планов для запросов. НО указание переменной `$game_id` прямо в теле запроса начисто убивает этот механизм, потому что с точки зрения оптимизатора запросы должны быть одинаковы с точностью до буквы. Поэтому подготавливаемые выражения, предложенные Visman не только спасают от SQL инъекций, но на некоторых СУБД и ускоряют работу всей системы в целом раза в 2, уменьшая объем кеша запросов и позволяя брать готовый план для запроса, а не компилировать его каждый раз заново

Comment: @Mike Я использую подготовленные выражения, и когда подставляется вместо $game_id число - то даже при повторном запросе - в это место подставиться опять же это же число. Вопрос совсем в другом, но спасибо за внимательность.

Comment: @user190134 Но ведь там наверное может быть и другое число. не зря же там переменная. а запросы `game_id = 1` и `game_id = 2` для кеша - разные. А вот с подготавливаемыми выражениями запрос будет вида `game_id = ?` В _тексте_ запроса всегда будет стоять знак вопроса. А уже позже вы привязываете (с помощью bind_param() или прямо в execute для pdo) к нему конкретное значение. И эти моменты драйвер работы с БД и сервер понимают и запрос кешируется с вопросительным знаком (или другим плейсхолдером), а параметры для него передаются отдельно

Comment: @user190134 по поводу объединения таблиц - навскидку сложно сказать как лучше все сделать не видя полную структуру данных. если данные можно объединить - попробуйте сделать смежную таблицу. если 4 указанные таблицы полностью независимы друг от друга, то для производительности имеет смысл вытаскивать данные из основной (server_transitions) напрямую, а из вспомогательных через запросы по первичному ключу (WHERE project_id, game_id и т.д.). в любом случае тот запрос, который у вас указан в вопросе приведет к full scan всех указанных таблиц, что не очень оптимально по скорости выполнения.

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov смотрел запрос через explain - вот что вышло Вроде-бы нету full scan, поправил вопрос добавил туда explain

Comment: @user190134 не вставилась ссылка

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov в вопросе обновил

Comment: @user190134 в принципе EXPLAIN показывает все хорошо, но вы и сам запрос переписали в сильно лучшую сторону)

Comment: @user190134 единственное, посмотрите целесообразно ли оставлять индекс по полю status (вторая строчка в EXPLAIN). он все равно не используется в этом запросе.

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov да, по статусу идет скажем так основная сортировка